# How to constantly scroll to the end of text in multiline text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm updating my text box with text using a timer. Each time timer ticks I'm being redirected to the beginning to the text typed in my multiline text box.

How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say that when you refresh, you could move the selection cursor to the end, then scroll the textbox 'til it's visible using ScrollToCaret.

That'll be something like

```
 yourtextbox.SelectionStart = yourtextbox.Text.Length
 yourtextbox.ScrollToCaret()
```

Comment: Ah! I was missing the first line of your code in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This works much better. It's better than Kotch's solution because there is no need constantly updating the position of cursor.

```
txtDisplay.AppendText(txtDisplay.SelectedText);
```

Comment: Certainly the easiest and most intuitive way to both append text to the text box buffer and keep the latest text addition in view.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `TextBox.Select` method:

```
textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

That will set the cursor to just past the last character in the text box.